# Would Perl 6 be soon included for all distributions of Linux?

Tags: perl, raku

Will Perl 6 soon included and will replace Perl 5 in all Linux distributions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It won't. Perl 5 and Perl 6 both are different languages.

You may want to read the related discussion at perlmonks on the topic: [Will Perl 6 Replace Perl 5?](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=815428)

Answer (score 7):

No. Perl6 will never replace Perl5. They're different languages.

Comment: Though, there would be a compatibility mode in Perl 6 to Perl 5 isn't it?

Comment: @e19293001: not really, no.

Comment: From Wikipedia: _Backward compatibility with earlier versions of Perl is not a goal, though a compatibility mode is part of the specification._ It doesn't sound like a no to me.

Comment: I'll believe it when I see it.

Comment: Sounds like a self-contradictory statement to me. I don't think anything can be understood from it.

Comment: Someone should definitely take a look at the specification and unravel the mystery :)

Comment: Did you mean: the implementation

Comment: Well just because it doesn't have that feature right now doesn't mean it won't in the future.

Comment: probably a reference to the long dead http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PONIE

Comment: Whether they are different languages or not, that doesn't answer the question about Perl 6's inclusion in linux, or if Perl 6 will replace Perl 5. If the question was "Will Python replace Perl 5" I bet the confusion would not be the same.